# Creating a trigger that checks if a ID data value exists in the database

Tags: sql-server

This trigger is made for INSERT and UPDATE commands. It does not allow a record to be updated or inserted in a 'Orders table' with a 'productID' or a 'customerID' not included in the database. If an INSERT or UPDATE command is executed with an incorrect 'productID' or 'customerID', display an error message.

Here's my trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OrdersTblTrigger

ON Orders_tbl

FOR INSERT, UPDATE 

AS

    BEGIN
        DECLARE     @ProdID VARCHAR(10),
                    @CustID VARCHAR(10)

        SET     @ProdID = (SELECT Prod_ID FROM inserted)
        SET     @CustID = (SELECT Cust_ID FROM inserted)


        IF @ProdID != (SELECT Prod_ID FROM Orders_tbl)
        AND @CustID != (SELECT Cust_ID FROM Orders_tbl)
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'That ID does not exist in the database! 
                Please try again.'
            END     
    END
```

Then, this code is used to test it:

```
INSERT INTO Orders_tbl
VALUES('Test1', '1', 90, 1, getdate(), null)
```

The second value is the CustomerID that I'm checking for. That '1' does not exist in the database.

However, when I run it I get:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure OrdersTblTrigger, Line 14
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

If I disable the trigger it works fine, the values get inserted into the Orders Table. So, there's something in the actual trigger. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Your database does not look good as the productId and customerId is checked inside the order table. By doing so if the trigger is active, then there will be no way to add a order with new customer/product Id. Your db should be normalized with a Product table and Customer Table,and implement the trigger below

Your original logic for the trigger is incorrect as it will only check the existence of 1 customer or product id.

```
CREATE TRIGGER OrdersTblTrigger

ON Orders_tbl

FOR INSERT, UPDATE 

AS

    BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN   products p on Prod_ID= p.id 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN customers c on Cust_ID= c.id
                         WHERE c.id is NULL or p.id is NULL
                 )

            BEGIN
                PRINT 'That ID does not exist in the database! 
                Please try again.'
                ROLLBACK ;
            END     
    END
```

If you think you need the solution with the current schema then change the `IF EXISTS` Part to

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted i
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN   Orders_tbl p on i.Prod_ID= p.Prod_ID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders_tbl c on i.Cust_ID= c.Cust_ID
                    WHERE c.Cust_ID is NULL or p.Prod_ID is NULL
             )
```

Comment: I'm not trying to add a new order with a new Product ID or Customer ID. I need to check if either one does NOT exist in the database. If they do not exist in the database, then they won't be added instead an error message should be thrown. Whereas, if they do exist in the database then it will be added.

Comment: Then change the `IF EXISTS` part to the second query mentioned in the answer

Comment: I did. Instead both codes now just add the order to my Orders_tbl regards if the Customer and Product ID exist or not.

Comment: There was a little join error in the query. I have updated it in the answer. Please try with it

Comment: Hmm... Nope. It still adds the new order to the table.

Comment: HA! I got it... The first time I ran it with the first part of the IF EXISTS it didn't work. Maybe I miss typed something, but now I included the Prodcuts_tbl and Customers_tbl from my Database. It woks!!!